Facing error when running data assistant of great expectations Python library
Setup and Create Expectation suit both running successfully in my system, but last setp of data assistant, i.e, run validation is giving the below error.
line 28, in <module>
    batch = context._get_batch_v2(batch_request)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: AbstractDataContext._get_batch_v2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expectation_suite_name'

I even tried with "get_batch", it's not working, Below I have added the code of run validation.

For the below code, I am getting the error:
# Load the batch of data
batch = context._get_batch_v2(batch_request)

# Run the validation
results = context.run_validation_operator(
    "action_list_operator",
    assets_to_validate=[batch],
    run_id="my_run_id"
)

